# Make a dark mode with JavaFx

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I was wondering if there is an easy way to make a dark mode using JavaFx and CSS. I have a MenuBar with a CheckMenuItem called 'Dark mode' and when I click it I want the scene to become dark and the text to become white.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23164205/2855515

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's been a while since I played with "theming" a JavaFX application, but from a while ago I have a CSS file:

```css
.root {
    -fx-base: #3f474f;
    -fx-accent: #e7eff7 ;
    -fx-default-button: #7f878f ;
    -fx-focus-color: #efefef;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: #efefef22;
    -fx-focused-text-base-color : ladder(
            -fx-selection-bar,
            -fx-light-text-color 45%,
            -fx-dark-text-color 46%,
            -fx-dark-text-color 59%,
            -fx-mid-text-color 60%
        );
    -fx-focused-mark-color : -fx-focused-text-base-color ;   

}

.text-input:focused {
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: ladder(
        -fx-highlight-fill,
        -fx-light-text-color 45%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  46%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  59%,
        -fx-mid-text-color   60%
    );
}
```

If you put this in a file, say `dark-theme.css`, you can do

```
checkMenuItem.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
    if (isSelected) {
        scene.getStyleSheets().add("dark-theme.css");
    } else {
        scene.getStyleSheets().remove("dark-theme.css");
    }
});
```

Comment: getting ` loadStylesheetUnPrivileged`? see : [... error when trying to use css stylesheet with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33764821/196507)

Answer (score 20):

Here's mine.

(Update) The previous one was too opaque.

```
.root { 
    -fx-accent: #1e74c6;
    -fx-focus-color: -fx-accent;
    -fx-base: #373e43;
    -fx-control-inner-background: derive(-fx-base, 35%);
    -fx-control-inner-background-alt: -fx-control-inner-background ;
}

.label{
    -fx-text-fill: lightgray;
}

.text-field {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: gray;
}

.titulo{
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
}

.button{
    -fx-focus-traversable: false;
}

.button:hover{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.separator *.line { 
    -fx-background-color: #3C3C3C;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}

.scroll-bar{
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-base,45%)
}

.button:default {
    -fx-base: -fx-accent ;
} 

.table-view{
    /*-fx-background-color: derive(-fx-base, 10%);*/
    -fx-selection-bar-non-focused: derive(-fx-base, 50%);
}

.table-view .column-header .label{
    -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;
    -fx-font-weight: none;
}

.list-cell:even,
.list-cell:odd,
.table-row-cell:even,
.table-row-cell:odd{    
    -fx-control-inner-background: derive(-fx-base, 15%);
}

.list-cell:empty,
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.list-cell,
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color:transparent;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful job styling

Answer (score 4):

the property base can be applied to every JavaFX type, This enables a color theme to be specified using a single base color for a JavaFx Node or Layout..., and to have variant colors (for its children) computed based on that base color!

in this case, you are trying to set the theme for the whole scene so you should apply the base color to the highest Component in the hierarchy which you can get by getting the root Node of your scene!

```
checkMenuItem.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
    if (isSelected) {
        scene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-base:black");
    } else {
        scene.getRoot().setStyle("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer for better understanding

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: this works perfectly fine, and the explanation is good enough

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to javafx and all, but I'm pretty sure creating **2 stylesheets** and switching between them would suffice.

Again if what I said was wrong, sorry, I'm new to javafx